# How can i verify the correct usage of an alt text with a tag

Tags: html, section508

Here is the alt text I am trying to verify:

```html
<a class="module-List-module-link—CtkbR—" href="/first/2041" alt="text">sample text (ABC)</a>
```

The original html snippet is:

```html
<a class="module-List-module-link—CtkbR—" href="/first/2041">sample text (ABC)</a>
```

I only added the `alt="text"` to make it `508` compliant. My question is: Is that valid?

I am taking my cue from:

```html
<article>
    <a href="news.html">
    <h3>Budget Debate Continues in Parliament</h3>
        <p class="subhead"><img class="alertimg" src="alerticon.png" alt="Breaking News" height="30" width="30">Members of Parliament continued vigorous debate on three challenging issues surrounding the upcoming year's budget.</p>
        <p>Read more</p>
    </a>

</article>
```

[reference: the WCAG section](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html)

When i scan the page using Compliance Sheriff, i get an issue:

**Anchor element does not have alternative text which describes purpose of the link**

for :

```
<a class="module-List-module-link—CtkbR—" href="/first/2041">sample text (ABC)</a>
```

Comment: "Valid" under which terms?

Comment: [Example 3 on that page](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html#H30-ex3) notes that an empty `alt` attribute on an `img` is okay if the link contains supplemental text that describes the link. The `alt` attribute is not valid on an anchor element.

Comment: @NicoHaase Valid in terms of HTML5 , and making sense in terms of 508 Compliance

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct usage of the `alt` attribute for an `<a>` element.

`alt` is used for **images** when the image cannot be loaded or understood by a user (e.g. because the image file didn't load, the browser is text only, or the user is blind).

Comment: The alt attribute must be specified for the IMG and AREA elements. It is optional for the INPUT and APPLET elements. from https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.8

Comment: @kamal — HTML 4 is obsolete. APPLET is obsolete and now non-confirming. IMG, AREA, and INPUT are all elements for including images.